# linking jQuery elements to show on hover

Tags: jquery, list, menu, jquery-hover

Is there a simple way to link jquery elements, for hovering. I have the jsbin at http://jsbin.com/useviz/3/edit I have it basically so that it doesn't close when you are hovering over the `ul` The problem arises when you move your mouse up above the element, or over to the next element. The original ul does not hide. This might sound confusing, but you will see if you look at the example above.

Comment: Please check my answer, if it's not as you require, let me know with brief description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to check if element you want to hide is exist or not, you can go hide it as you want. I've added `$(".sub_menu").hide(700);` to every mousehover functions and it works! see http://jsbin.com/useviz/6/

Answer (score 1):

something like this,

live demo [**here**](http://jsbin.com/useviz/4/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#servicebutton").mouseenter(function () {
        $('.sub_menu').hide();
        $('.sub_menu1').show(700);
    });

    $('.sub-menu1').mouseleave(function () {
         $('.sub_menu1').hide(700);
    });

    $("#packagebutton").mouseenter(function () {
         $('.sub_menu').hide();
         $('.sub_menu2').show(700);
    }); 

    $('.sub-menu2').mouseleave(function () {
         $('.sub_menu2').hide(700);
    });

    $("#productbutton").mouseenter(function () {
       $('.sub_menu').hide();
       $('.sub_menu3').show(700);
    });

    $('.sub-menu2').mouseleave(function () {
       $('.sub_menu3').hide(700);
    });

  /* catch-all for submenus */
  $('.sub_menu').mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).hide(700);
  });
});
```